# Can't obtain user likes in some cases using facebook graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a problem with a facebook app. I want to know if the user likes a page to show one content or another. The problem is that some users click on like button but the app dont read it from facebook graph API. Here is the code I'm using to check if a user likes the page:

```
$appID = '171296629176';

$resp = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$user."/likes?access_token=".$facebook->getAccessToken()."&limit=9999");
$data = json_decode($resp,true);

$liked = 0;

$likes_array = $data['data'];
$likes_next = '';
if(($data != null) && (array_key_exists('paging',$data)) && (array_key_exists('next',$data['paging']))){
    $likes_next = $data['paging']['next'];
}

foreach($likes_array as $like)
{
    if($appID == $like['id']){
        $liked = 1;     
    }
}

while(strlen($likes_next) > 0){
    $resp = file_get_contents($likes_next);
    $data = json_decode($resp,true);

    $likes_array = $data['data'];
    $likes_next = '';
    if(($data != null) && (array_key_exists('paging',$data)) && (array_key_exists('next',$data['paging']))){
        $likes_next = $data['paging']['next'];
    }

    foreach($likes_array as $like)
    {
        if($appID == $like['id']){
            $liked = 1;     
        }
    }
}
```

In some cases it isn't working. I don't know if facebook API returns an empty list of likes or if it returns an incomplete list. With my account and others it works ok and I can't contact the users that are experiencing the issue to test the app.

Thanks in advance.
Alfonso.